# trace function ($2\times2$) with ordered bases as linear transformation

Tags: matrices, transformation, trace

We got trace function as following:

$$\operatorname{tr}\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b\\
        c & d\\
        \end{pmatrix}=a+d$$

So now have to write down $[\operatorname{tr}]_{S_1,S_2}$, where ordered bases are the standard bases:

$$S_2=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix},
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1\\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix},
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0\\
        1 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix},
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right\}, S_1=\{1\} $$

I'm pretty sure its $S_1=\{1\} $, not the $I$ (identity) matrix. Since we are doing transformation from Matrix to number ($4\dim$ to $1\dim$)

So the question is: "can the trace function be represented as a linear transformation?"

Please advice.

Comment: Is $\text{tr}(cA + B) = c\,\text{tr}(A) + \text{tr}(B)$? Yes $\Rightarrow$ $\text{tr}$ is a linear transformation, No $\Rightarrow$ it isn't.

Comment: Represent $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}$ in terms of the basis elements, then write down the transform in terms of the basis elements of $S_1$. You will get the representation from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the basis elements be named $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ in the order given in the OP. Then the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ can be written as $ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3 + de_4$ = $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}$.

$
\text{tr}\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = a + d \Rightarrow \\
\text{tr}(ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3 + de_4) = 1a + 0b + 0c + 1d
$

From this, the matrix representing $\text{tr}$ is $\boxed{(1\ 0\ 0\ 1)}$.

Comment: the following $tr(ae_1+be_2+ce_3+de_4)=1a+0b+0c+1d$ does make sense for me now :))

Comment: so the rank of tr matrix is 4? or 1

Comment: @MotherLand It's $1$, of course! Only a $4 \times 4$ or higher order matrix could possibly have rank $4$. But you don't need to look at the matrix to find the rank. The rank of a transformation is the dimension of its image space. Here the image space is one-dimensional, so the rank is $1$.

Comment: @Vinay for nullity theorem: nullity(Tr) + rank(Tr) = 3 + 1 = 4? (3 elements in nullspace, rank = 1 and 4 total elements) Seems everything is correct. Did i apply the rule correctly?

Comment: @MotherLand Yes, except it's not the number of *elements* that's $3$, it's the dimension. The dimension of the null space is $3$. All matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0 & b\\c & 0\end{pmatrix} = be_2 + ce_4$ and $\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\0 & -a\end{pmatrix} = ae_1 - ae_4 = a(e_1 - e_4)$ are mapped to $0$. So the nullspace is $\text{span}(\{e_2, e_3, e_1 - e_4\})$, which has dimension $3$.

Comment: i found the following, nullspace of [1, 0, 0, 1] is $ker(tr)=x4*[-1;0;0;1]$ so $dim(ker(tr))=1$ or each of these zeros in solspace add 1 to the nullity?

Comment: @MotherLand Why are the second and third components $0$? They can be anything $(a\ b\ c\ -a)$ is mapped to $0$ (check this).

Comment: @MotherLand $\text{tr}\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow a + d = 0 \Rightarrow d = -a$. It says nothing about $b$ and $c$, which means they can take any values. So there are three independent components ($a$, $b$, and $c$, with $d = -a$). This makes the dimension (of the null space) $3$.

Comment: Oh, I see now, so because of the zeros in $tr=[−1;0;0;1]$ it is actually $ker(tr)=x_2*[0;0;0;0]+x_3*[0;0;0;0]+x_4∗[−1;0;0;1]$ and therefore $dim(ker(tr))=3$

Comment: @MotherLand That's correct!

Comment: Thank you so much for the cooperation, things become clearer now, and I'm almost ready for my final))

Comment: little update, the basis for $ker(tr)$ is $[0;0;0;0],[0;0;0;0],[-1;0;0;1]$? since $dim(ker(tr))=3$

Comment: @MotherLand You can't have null vectors in the basis (because a set with null vectors is dependent, for one thing, and null vectors are useless for making new vectors, for another). The basis vectors are $e_2, e_3, e_1 - e_4$, that is $[0\ 1\ 0\ 0],\ [0\ 0\ 1\ 0],\ [1\ 0\ 0\ -1]$.

Comment: @MotherLand Ah, I see that earlier you had written $x_2[0\ 0\ 0\ 0] + \ldots$. No, that should be $x_2[0\ 1\ 0\ 0] + \ldots$, sorry for not pointing that out earlier. The elements of the kernel are of the form $[-x_4\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4]$ (to correct what you wrote).

Answer (score 2):

$tr$ is represented by the $1\times 4$ matrix $(1,0,0,1)$.

Comment: how can we multiply 2x2 matrix by 1x4? O_O

Comment: @MotherLand You can, because the "matrix" is a vector.

Comment: We do not. We multiply it by the vector $\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}$ representing your $2\times 2$ matrix in the basis $S_2$.

Comment: so $[tr]_{S1,S2}=[1,0,0,1]$? since we use $S_1=\{1\}$ to represent the 1x4 matrix. Lets say if our $S_1=\{2\}$, then $[tr]_{S1,S2}=[0.5,0,0,0.5]$ так?)

Comment: Exactly/в точности

Comment: @Vladimir Lets say if our $S_1=\{2\}$ (or if in $S_2$ instead of 1 we got 2,), then [tr]S1,S2=[0.5,0,0,0.5]?  right? Большое спасибо за помощь (:

Comment: @MotherLand Yes, sure

Comment: But if in $S_2$ we have $2$ everywhere instead of $1$, then $[tr]=(2,0,0,2)$.